# значение типа "const char*" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "char *"

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, const, строковый-литерал

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h> 

struct card {
    char *face;
    char *suit;
};

typedef struct card Card;

int main()
{
    Card deck[52];
    char *face[] = { "Ace","Deuce","Three","Four","Five",
    "Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten",
    "Jack","Queen","King" };
    char *suit[] = { "Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades" };
}
```

Comment: А **вопрос** в чем? Это информация - что нельзя...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строковые литералы константны. Т.е. их, например, компилятор может разместить в какой-нибудь памяти только для чтения, например.

А если бы их можно было присваивать неконстантному указателю, то вы бы через такой указатель могли бы их изменять.

Что неверно.

Потому и запрещено...

Пробуйте

```
const char *face[] = ...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Если ответ вас устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый.

Comment: @IrzileySayin ...нажав на зеленую галочку слева.